# Problem creating a link between SQL Server Standard edition and SQL Express edition

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to establish a connection between two SQL severs located in different location and trying to read/fetch the tables. When I connect the remote Standard SQL Server from SQL Server Express and fetch table, it works fine. When I try to connect SQL Server Express from Standard SQL Server, I get an error Msg. Just to mention that I do have the writes to read, create, update tables in the Standard SQL Server.

Error Msg is:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSaddserver_internal, Line
> 34 [Batch Start Line 2] User does not have permission to perform this
> action.

Remote SQL Server is "DKLYDB3" and
Local SQL Server is "PC89450\SQLEXPRESS"

Query which works fine is below.

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver  @server='DKLYDB3';
SELECT * 
FROM [DKLYDB3].BRISK_AIS.dbo.Crossline;
```

Query which does not work is here.

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver  @server='PC89450\SQLEXPRESS';
SELECT * 
FROM [PC89450\SQLEXPRESS].BRISK_AIS.dbo.Crossline;
```

Comment: do you have privileges to execute the sp_addlinkedserver on the DKLYDB3 instance? you need `ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER` [permission to execute it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions).

Comment: _I do have the writes to read..._ That does not mean you have the appropriate permissions to add a linked server. Now would be a good time to have a discussion with the group responsible for managing your systems. Adding a linked server is something that needs to be documented and needs to be added to the disaster recovery plan.

Comment: Hi both: Today I discuss this issue with our IT section. They are not yet able to figure that part out. Then I myself tried to compare the privileges  I have in local SQL Express edition with the Standard SQL remote server. In the local Express version, under Object Explorer, under Security, in Login properties (use mapping), I am marked as db_owner and under Server Role marked as sysadmin. May be these two additional privileges are the reason for success in Local DB Server. 
In the Standard SQL server I added myself as db_owner but still not work. I am not able to change sysadmin myself.

Comment: Tomorrow I will ask IT section to change add myself for sysadmin. I do not know if this will work. I do not know either if they allow me to have this privilege. Apart from these two things I mentioned, I do not know if I have any other privilege in Local SQL server which I do not have in Standard SQL remote server. Everything else looks same.

Comment: As a sysadmin you'll definitely be able to create it. A sysadmin can do anything on a SQL Server instance, it's the highest privilege level a user can be. But it might be way too much.

Comment: @ Ronaldo: I have now enabled ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER. Now the connection is made successfully. But when I run a query I get different error.

Comment: Error is.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "PC89450\SQLEXPRESS" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "PC89450\SQLEXPRESS" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".

Comment: Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].

Comment: Is your SQLEXPRESS instance configured to [allow remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298469/set-sql-server-express-2017-to-allow-remote-connections)?